# regular expression to find and select all code in a css block

Tags: regex, eclipse

Can someone help me with the regular expression to find and select code inside a specific css class in eclipse
for eg:
I have a class:

```
.addContentLink {
    position: relative;
    left: 470px;
}
```

so I want to select code inside the opening and closing braces....thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (?s).*?\{(.*?)\}.*?
```

Please see the demo

http://regex101.com/r/uU0kC7/1

Edited

```
(?s)\.addContentLink.*?\{(.*?)\}.*?
```

This will work for one specific class .But if there are multiple then a pattern would be needed.

Comment: thnaks for reply, but it doesnt select blocks with multiline code, and also where do i put the class name ie: ".addContentLink"?

Comment: which language are you using.You just have to pass the whole string and add multiline option. In python it would be like 
patter=.re.compile(r".*?\{(.*?)\}.*?",re.M)
patter.match(your_string).groups()

Comment: i have a external css file in which i need to change code for all media queries...and i want eclipse to find all code blocks with specific css class name

Comment: it will select multiline as ?s does that.You can apply this over any file.

Comment: thanks buddy, but where do i mention the class name??

Comment: dats the only classname or there can be others as well?

Comment: it can be any class name, i have a lot of classes in multiple media queries, thats the problem.

Comment: Let us <a href="http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59104/discussion-between-vks-and-mckenzie">continue this discussion in chat</a>.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the accepted answer, but I am adding this which will support line breaks too.

```
.*?\{([\s\S]*?)\}.*?
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/rb4syz/1